# GROUP BY in php 5.6.25 won't work

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

after upgrading my wampserver 3.0.6 with Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14 PHP 5.6.25 GROUP BY sql statement won't work.

Eg:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM `activity_list` GROUPED BY `Category`;"; //- NOT WORKING
$query ="SELECT * FROM `activity_list`;"; //- WORKS FINE.
```

Thanks

Comment: __GROUPED__? Really?

Comment: Bro .. I think Its... `GROUP BY` ...

Comment: hahaha this worked in your previous version? GROUPED ?

Comment: :) careless php developer, maybe a student, i think u should review some sql basic knowledge.

Comment: This is a legitimate question. It is coincidence that it stopped working with a server upgrade. Your query probably never worked because your select * returns fields that aren't part of the group by clause, or used in an aggregate statement. I bet the upgrade changed some settings that are now making this apparent.

Comment: Now I am forced to change in all my codes 

$query ="SELECT * FROM `activity_list` GROUP BY `Category`;";

To

$query ="SELECT  DISTINCT 'Category' FROM `activity_list`;";

Answer (score 1):

**i think it's .. `GROUP BY`**  : Try This

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM activity_list GROUP BY Category;";
```

Comment: Sorry I meant $query ="SELECT * FROM `activity_list` GROUP BY `Category`;"; //- NOT WORKING